# Align elements of content block in html using .css file

Tags: html, css

I have a block in html and I need to align text and image in it using only .css file. Text should be on the left side and image on the right. I am completely new to css, so not sure where to start. As such, any advice would be very appreciated.

```
<div class="tm-content-box flex-2-col">

  <div class="padding-medium flex-item tm-team-description-container flex-item">
    <h2 class="tm-section-title">Some Text</h2>
    <p class="tm-section-description">Some More Text</p>
    <p class="tm-section-description">Some More Text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <img src="img/image1.jpg" alt="image1">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Judging from the CSS classes you already have, you seem to be using a CSS framework. Please create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including all the CSS you already use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply add display flex like this:

```css
.tm-content-box {
  display: flex;
}
```

I recommend you check the CSS flexbox. It will help you to make a more complicated design using plain CSS. You can check it from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)